# Social Media Widget only appers on pages and posts not my gallery?

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins, widget, social-media

I'm using Social Media Widget together with the theme touchfolio.

I would like it to appear bottom left on all my page, post and galleries but don't know how to fix this.
As it is now it don't appear on my gallery.

If you click on "About" or "Feed" you can see the icons on the bottom left.

Can someone please help me with this problem? Thanks

http://new.karimphoto.com/

http://wordpress.org/plugins/social-media-widget/

Theme: http://dimsemenov.com/themes/touchfolio/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see there is no widget area on the front/gallery page.

If you look in page.php in the theme it ends with:

```
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And the gallery template(ds-gallery-template.php) only ends with:

```
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

So if you add `<?php get_sidebar(); ?>` just before  `<?php get_footer(); ?>` you will be okay. Lycka till!

Comment: I still have some issues on http://new.karimphoto.com/gallery-category/stories/#tahrir It appears everywhere if you navigate through the site with using the arrows but if I click on stories, it will not show? Thanks for your time.

Comment: It is there for me if i click the link. cant see it missing on any page when looking.

Comment: I found it. added <?php get_sidebar(); ?> to /taxonomy-ds-gallery-category.php